# VSTS: Using $(BuildID) as an argument in a build step

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

I want to provide the build ID as an argument to some script in my build:

[image: BuildID]

But this does not parse into the build's ID. Instead it is used literally.  See output:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o C:\agent\_work\50\a\MyProject.Api --version-suffix $(BuildID)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this format: $(Build.BuildId)